# Nginx self-signed certificate isn't working on a Vagrant VM

Tags: ssl, nginx, vagrant

We're running Vagrant VMs here.  On a VM, I installed nginx. I then created a self-signed certificate. When I look at the certificate's innards, I see:

```
subject= /C=US/ST=IN/L=myCity/O=My Company/OU=MyProduct/CN=silly.com/emailAddress=info@silly.com
```

This is obviously sanitized. I believe this certificate is supposed to work for `silly.com`. Do I interpret this correctly?

On my laptop, I added a hostfile entry to map silly.com to the appropriate IP address.

On the VM, I added the following configuration to /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
 # HTTPS server  server {
    listen 443;
    server_name silly.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/silly.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/silly.key;  }
```

When I browse the site, the port 80 http screen is displayed properly. When I browse with `https://silly.com`, however, the https portion is rejected and the non-SSL screen is displayed. (I think I clicked 'proceed' while experimenting...)

I commented from the nginx.conf file all lines relating to port 80. Then I restarted nginx. I will get the same success on port 80 and failure on port 443 as I did before.

I tested the config file with `nginx -t`. It reported no errors.

Would someone offer a debugging tip, please?

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the fact that your opening `server {` block is effectively commented out because of the `# HTTPS server` comment.  You should actually be getting an error on this config because the closing `}` is there.  Perhaps this is preventing you from restarting Nginx.